# How can I save multiple rows in one mutation in graphql and mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, express-graphql

Here I want to add multiple thoughts in one mutation query.
How can I achieve this:

```
mutation{
  savethoughts(data: [{id:1,name:"a"},data: {id:2,name:"b"}]){
    id
  }
}
```

Comment: mutation { savethoughts(data: [{ id: 1, name: "a" }, { id: 2, name: "b" }]) { id } }

Answer (score 2):

For save multiple records in database you need to follow every steps carefully

For example

```
mutation{
  setMultipleRecord(data: [{title: "first Title", name: "First"},
                           {title: "Second Title", name: "Second"}])
}
```

You must have schema type

```
  `
  .......
  input Record {
    title: String!
    name: String!
  }
  .....
  `
```

And add Mutation as given that

```
  type Mutation/type RootMutation { {
    ......
    setMultipleRecord(data: [Record]): String!
  }
```

Here you can see **Record** is input type schema object where is **data** parameter holding variable which we are using to get data object.

you can give any name instead of data also change in the argument in mutation

Now in resolver function a

```
  Mutation: {
    setMultipleRecord: async(args, { data }) => {
      console.log(data)
      //Here data contain data which you passed which is
      // [{title: "first Title", name: "First"},
      //  {title: "Second Title", name: "Second"}]
      // Perform operation as your requirement
      // Please return String 
    }
  }
```

Now you can change name as par your requirement of object.

You made it successfully...

Comment: This looks awesome, thankyou @Ashok its what I need. However i dont get the nested mutation syntax, can you explain a little?

Comment: ah i get it. the '\' was just you saying use type mutation or root mutation ;)